# how to split mysql query condition

Tags: mysql

i was inserted query in database with day and time  like this

```
username    email       Registration Date and Time
----------  ----------  ---------- --------------------
 Tom       Tom@xxx.com   2020-06-24 17:41:03

 jerry     jer@xxx.com   2020-05-24 23:41:03

 puppy      pup@xxx.com   2020-04-24 3:41:03

 dolly      doll@xxx.com   2020-04-24 16:41:03
```

now iwant to fetch deatails only  with date

**my query**

```
     select * from  table where Registration Date and Time= 2020-06-24;
```

How to split condition , bcoz i want fetch day registerd user details please help me

Comment: what is the data type for `Registration Date and Time`?

Comment: @Kevin varchar is the data type

Comment: Provide real table's DDL and source data example (3-5 rows) as INSERT INTO script.

Comment: @Akina i have shows 4 rows  same db also

Comment: I have asked "as INSERT INTO script"... your table tells nothing. And where is table's DDL (its CREATE TABLE script)?

Comment: @Akina waht there is no problem with insert .... i want to get   results with date wise

Comment: I am not interested does your insert was successful. But this query text will show precisely what values were inserted. And where, finally, is the table structure?

Comment: For us to understand how to do this, we'd like to be able to do it ourselves. For this it would be helpful if you could provide with a `create table` statement as you must have used, and the `insert into` statement, that you say you have performed successfully.

Comment: @MadhuMunna welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a service for solving problems of users. It is a Q&A system containing questions that could be valid for many other users who come to the same situation. That is why you need to be careful in wording your questions clearly and properly, and giving all details that are needed to understand your question. Users above asked you to clarify the question. If you will not do it, your question will be likely deleted soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(Registration Date and Time) = '2020-06-24'
```

`DATE` type format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) link out as well, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes i was tried same like this but not working ... coz i was stored data with varchar data type format

Comment: @MadhuMunna *coz i was stored data with varchar data type format* This cannot be a source of failure - MySQL's datatype system is soft and context-dependent, shown values must be correctly treated as datetime.

Comment: I guess WHHERE is a typo and Registration Date and Time needs to be quoted with backticks.AND I wonder what not working means...

Comment: @P.Salmon i want know about split condition values

Comment: @Madhu Munna make the corrections and this answer should work - if it does not then tell us in what way it does not.

Comment: of course .... how to convert data ( varchar ) into datetime format any idea

Comment: @Madhu Munna this answer converts to date why do you want datetime when your code is only interested in date? And do add your expected output as text to the question.